# > Could not open proj generic class cache for build file

Tags: flutter, caching, build, project, root

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Users\kumar\Desktop\Emart_V2.1_Source_Code\apps\eMart_Customer\android> ./gradlew singingreport

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\kumar\Desktop\Emart_V2.1_Source_Code\apps\eMart_Customer\android\build.gradle' line: 31
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\kumar\Desktop\Emart_V2.1_Source_Code\apps\eMart_Customer\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\kumar.gradle\caches\7.3.3\scripts\eg36hfkr63j7b69mkqrsgpjs0).
> > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
PS C:\Users\kumar\Desktop\Emart_V2.1_Source_Code\apps\eMart_Customer\android>

Please Help Me

please fix this error and help me .